# Numerical Approximation for the Variance of the Log of the Sum of RVs

Tags: r, variance, random-variable, lognormal-distribution

I'm interested in the variance of the logarithm of the sum of 2 independent, log-normal random variables,

$$
\begin{align*}
Var\big(\log(X_1 + X_2)\big) \\[1em]
X_1 \sim LN(\mu_1, \sigma_1) \\[1em]
X_2 \sim LN(\mu_2, \sigma_2)
\end{align*}
$$

where $\mu$ is the log mean and $\sigma$ is the log std. dev.  This needs to be done numerically.  I've been playing around with the `distr` and `distrEx` R packages to achieve this.  A MWE,

```
################
## Setup data ##
################

sdX1 = 0.33
sdX2 = 0.70
muX1 = log(32765) - 0.5 * sdX1^2
muX2 = log(52650) - 0.5 * sdX2^2

#################
## Convolution ##
#################

L1 = distr::Lnorm(meanlog = muX1, sdlog = sdX1)
L2 = distr::Lnorm(meanlog = muX2, sdlog = sdX2)

## Integration
L1plusL2 = L1 + L2

## Variance
distrEx::var(L1plusL2, fun = log)
[1] 0.5630171

#################
## MC approach ##
#################

X1 = rlnorm(1e08, meanlog = muX1, sdlog = sdX1)
X2 = rlnorm(1e08, meanlog = muX2, sdlog = sdX2)
var(log(X1 + X2))
[1] 0.1843613
```

However, the answer from the `distrEx` is wildly different from when I use a Monte Carlo approximation.  I would expect them to be somewhat different, as they're approximations, but not that different.  Am I doing something wrong?